Aparecen botones pero sin estilo y sin evento
Estoy aprendiendo Javascript y estoy quise realizar un ejercicio que incluye HTML, Java y Css. El ejercicio se trata de hacer tres botones con un pequeño texto al ser seleccionadas. Sin embargo, me quedaron los tres botones, pero no me quedaron con el estilo que diseñé, y tampoco me quedaron con un evento. Este es el código:


const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
const contenidoTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".contenido-tab");

tabs.forEach((tab) => {
  tab.addEventListener("click", () => {
  //Ocultar todo el contenido de las pestañas
  contenidoTabs.forEach((contenido)=>{
      contenido.style.display = "none";
  });

  //Mostrar el contenido correspondiente a la pestaña seleccionada
  const contenidoId = tab.getAttribute("id");
  const contenidoSeleccionado = document.getElementById("contenido${contenidoId}");
  contenidoSeleccionado.style.display = "block";
  });

});
.tabs {
  display: flex;
}

.tab {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contenido-tab {
  display: none;
}
<div class="tabs">
  <button class="tab" id="inicio">Inicio</button>
  <button class="tab" id="acerca">Acerca de</button>
  <button class="tab" id="contacto">Contacto</button>
</div>

<div id="contenidoInicio" class="contenido-tab">
  <h2>Bienvenido a la página de Inicio</h2>`
  <p>Este es el contenido de la página de inicio.</p>
</div>

<div id="contenidoAcerca" class="contenido-tab">
  <h2>Acerca de nosotros</h2>`
  <p>Este es el contenido de la página "Acerca de".</p>
</div>

<div id="ContenidoContacto" class="contenido-tab">
  <h2>Contáctanos</h2>
  <p>Este es el contenido de la página "Contacto". </p>
</div>



Ojalá me puedan colaborar



ok y en la consola de desarrollador sale algun mensaje???

"El término "<" no se reconoce como un nombre de un cmdlet. función, archivo de script, o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha rute es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo"
Y siempre es con el signo "menor que".

ok eso quiere decir que hay codigo mencionado que tiene agun problema que no has mostrado ... te sugiero editar tu publicacion y agregar, capturas y el codigo relacionados pues pareciera incluso ser problema con el backend

@FranciscoNuñezIALover arriba puse la imagen del código

Hola, el codigo no se debe poner el imagen... dudo quea alguien aqui pretenda re-escribir el codigo para ayudarte... pon el codigo en texto resaltado por favor.

Luego de limpiar tu pregunta no veo errores en tu CSS, pero si los tienes en el javascript, principalmente en esta línea:
const contenidoSeleccionado = document.getElementById("contenido${contenidoId}");

La cual debes reemplazar por:
const contenidoSeleccionado =  document.getElementById(`contenido${contenidoId}`);

Ya que las Plantillas literales deben usar "tildes invertidas" no comillas dobles como tú lo estás haciendo.
Luego tú has creado una lógica con los ID, por ejemplo, el tab se llama inicio y su contenido se llama contenidoInicio, pero al concatenar te quedaría contenidoinicio (con la i minúscula), por lo que debes cambiar los Id's
Luego, el último div tiene como ContenidoContacto con C mayúscula en la palabra "contenido"


const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
const contenidoTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".contenido-tab");

tabs.forEach((tab) => {
  tab.addEventListener("click", () => {
  //Ocultar todo el contenido de las pestañas
  contenidoTabs.forEach((contenido)=>{
      contenido.style.display = "none";
  });

  //Mostrar el contenido correspondiente a la pestaña seleccionada
  const contenidoId = tab.getAttribute("id");
  const contenidoSeleccionado = document.getElementById(`contenido${contenidoId}`);
  contenidoSeleccionado.style.display = "block";
  });

});
.tabs {
  display: flex;
}

.tab {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contenido-tab {
  display: none;
}
<div class="tabs">
  <button class="tab" id="Inicio">Inicio</button>
  <button class="tab" id="Acerca">Acerca de</button>
  <button class="tab" id="Contacto">Contacto</button>
</div>

<div id="contenidoInicio" class="contenido-tab">
  <h2>Bienvenido a la página de Inicio</h2>`
  <p>Este es el contenido de la página de inicio.</p>
</div>

<div id="contenidoAcerca" class="contenido-tab">
  <h2>Acerca de nosotros</h2>`
  <p>Este es el contenido de la página "Acerca de".</p>
</div>

<div id="contenidoContacto" class="contenido-tab">
  <h2>Contáctanos</h2>
  <p>Este es el contenido de la página "Contacto". </p>
</div>




te dieron un downvote porque... porque si, porque les caes mal

@infinit3Loop__ Es extraño, porque generalmente solo las personas que me llegan a conocer bien les caigo mal. Gracias por la preocupación, pero a mí los downvotes que me dan me tienen sin cuidado.
